# Postgresql assign group number by unique set of column values

Tags: sql, postgresql, set, grouping, unique

In my view I want to assign group numbers for rows. Group is described as unic set of values from some table column.

[image: example]

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8ea36c234ba378f08d2a870b5f695bba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `row_number()`:

```
select column1, row_number() over (partition by column1 order by column1) as group_nr
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e4fcdc0a07814408d09e1fffdd86b5ae) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: No. In your solution I get 6 groups but there should be only 3. Here is example in dbfiddle.uk: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9da1899f08d2e2ca9d436a2abf47eb2e

Comment: @Andrew_Miller . . . I fixed the answer and added a dbfiddle.

Comment: I said there should be 3 but I was wrong - there should be 2 groups. And yes, now it works. Thank you very much!